# External SSD not properly detected if connected before boot

Tags: usb, boot

I have 2 Samsung 870 EVOs with USB bridges that I'd like to connect to RPi4.

It seems to work fine when I connect them after the RPi4 has already booted and I can see them properly using lsblk.

However if they're connected before booting RPi4 they show up as /dev/sda and sdb, but not in lsblk.

In this situation they're unusable until they're reconnected as all operations fail - even fdisk can't open them.

Any tips?

EDIT:

dmesg output per @DmitryGrigoryev

```
[    0.103603] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbfs
[    0.103658] usbcore: registered new interface driver hub
[    0.103709] usbcore: registered new device driver usb
[    1.511841] usbcore: registered new interface driver lan78xx
[    1.511900] usbcore: registered new interface driver smsc95xx
[    1.514063] usb usb1: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0002, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.514077] usb usb1: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.514088] usb usb1: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.514099] usb usb1: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-1032-raspi xhci-hcd
[    1.514109] usb usb1: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.515810] usb usb2: New USB device found, idVendor=1d6b, idProduct=0003, bcdDevice= 5.04
[    1.515823] usb usb2: New USB device strings: Mfr=3, Product=2, SerialNumber=1
[    1.515833] usb usb2: Product: xHCI Host Controller
[    1.515843] usb usb2: Manufacturer: Linux 5.4.0-1032-raspi xhci-hcd
[    1.515853] usb usb2: SerialNumber: 0000:01:00.0
[    1.851054] usb 2-1: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    1.872362] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=1561, bcdDevice= 2.14
[    1.872378] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    1.872390] usb 2-1: Product: SABRENT
[    1.872400] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: SABRENT
[    1.872410] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: DB9876543214E
[    1.998672] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
[    2.149235] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=2109, idProduct=3431, bcdDevice= 4.20
[    2.149253] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=1, SerialNumber=0
[    2.149265] usb 1-1: Product: USB2.0 Hub
[    2.275009] usb 2-2: new SuperSpeed Gen 1 USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.296298] usb 2-2: New USB device found, idVendor=152d, idProduct=1561, bcdDevice= 2.14
[    2.296316] usb 2-2: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[    2.296327] usb 2-2: Product: SABRENT
[    2.296337] usb 2-2: Manufacturer: SABRENT
[    2.296347] usb 2-2: SerialNumber: DB9876543214E
[    2.388561] usbcore: registered new interface driver usb-storage
[    2.422719] usbcore: registered new interface driver uas
[    2.450667] usb 1-1.3: new full-speed USB device number 3 using xhci_hcd
[    2.559173] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=0c40, idProduct=7a1c, bcdDevice= 1.05
[    2.559190] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0
[    2.559202] usb 1-1.3: Product: AirMouse Remote
[    2.559212] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Anycon
[    2.599552] usbcore: registered new interface driver usbhid
[    2.599564] usbhid: USB HID core driver
[    2.619437] input: Anycon AirMouse Remote as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.0/0003:0C40:7A1C.0001/input/input0
[    2.679134] hid-generic 0003:0C40:7A1C.0001: input,hidraw0: USB HID v1.01 Keyboard [Anycon AirMouse Remote] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input0
[    2.680911] input: Anycon AirMouse Remote Mouse as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:0C40:7A1C.0002/input/input1
[    2.681439] input: Anycon AirMouse Remote System Control as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:0C40:7A1C.0002/input/input2
[    2.739093] input: Anycon AirMouse Remote Consumer Control as /devices/platform/scb/fd500000.pcie/pci0000:00/0000:00:00.0/0000:01:00.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.3/1-1.3:1.1/0003:0C40:7A1C.0002/input/input3
[    2.739466] hid-generic 0003:0C40:7A1C.0002: input,hidraw1: USB HID v1.01 Mouse [Anycon AirMouse Remote] on usb-0000:01:00.0-1.3/input1
[    3.329614] usb_phy_generic phy: phy supply vcc not found, using dummy regulator
[   10.737596] usbcore: registered new interface driver brcmfmac
```

Comment: Check the kernel log (`sudo dmesg | grep usb`). My guess is the SSDs exceed 1.2A of USB current allowance if they start at exactly the same time. You might want to check [`this q&a`](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/104038/33476) for details and possible solutions.

Comment: the USB->SATA adapter(s) may be at fault - what are you using?

Comment: I'm using a Sabrent bridge.

Comment: According to 870 EVO spec they should use less than 1A at max power each, so this should be ok?

Comment: @DmitryGrigoryev your answer seems to be correct. I've purchased a powered USB hub and not it works. Feel free to post an answer and I'll mark it as a solution.

Comment: @Alesito Sorry, no time. I'm glad you solved it though, have a +1!